# Convert ordered dictionary to different format

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I need to convert the given list of ordered dictionaries in a different format with minimal time complexity. Code for reproducing example:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

list_of_dicts = [OrderedDict([('key_a','value_a'),('key_b','value_b')]), 
                 OrderedDict([('key_a','value_c'),('key_b','value_d')]),
                 OrderedDict([('key_a','value_e'),('key_b','value_f')])]
```

Need to convert the above to the following (**WITHOUT USING EXPLICIT FOR LOOP**):

```
convertedDictionary = [OrderedDict([('value_a','value_b')]),
                       OrderedDict([('value_c','value_d')]),
                       OrderedDict([('value_e','value_f')])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first step: get the lists: simple enough mapping `dict.values` to the dicts:

```
>>> list(map(dict.values,list_of_dicts))
[['value_a', 'value_b'], ['value_c', 'value_d'], ['value_e', 'value_f']]
```

Now for the final result, without loops, the only alternative is `map` with `lambda` but it's ugly

```
>>> list(map(lambda x : OrderedDict((x,)),map(dict.values,list_of_dicts)))
[OrderedDict([('value_a', 'value_b')]),
 OrderedDict([('value_c', 'value_d')]),
 OrderedDict([('value_e', 'value_f')])]
```

which is much better (and probably faster) with an outer list comprehension:

```
[OrderedDict((x,)) for x in map(dict.values,list_of_dicts)]
```

note: why using `OrderedDict` if you only have 1 value per dictionary? why storing only one value per dictionary? Unless this is an initialization step, the data model looks dubious.